# Перенос статичного сайта на react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, статистика

Проблема. 
Есть сайт с кучей разных html, в каждой jq скрипты, на главной странице просто ссылки на другие страницы, в общем полный адъ.
Каким образом безболезненно осуществить переход на реакт. есть идейка постепенно создавать компоненты и на страницах, где он используется подключать его и редерить определенный компонент.
Вот только каким образом это сделать не представляю.
Еще думал, перенести для начала главную страницу, а с использование react-route отдавать старые страницы или компоненты по мере их написания

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд - максимально безболезненно будет тогда, когда вы максимально быстро получите результат, а дальше будете улучшать код. Удобнее, когда всё работает, и вы вносите правки, чем когда вы сразу пытаетесь сделать всё хорошо, но даже не можете посмотреть текущий результат. 
Алгоритм:

1. Первая цель - сделать "одностраничник" (для чего и переносится
   всё на React)  Сделайте страницы через react-route.
2. После
   делайте оптимизацию кода   Выделите основные компоненты
   (header/footer) и используйте их во всех страницах По очереди
   разбивайте каждую страницу на компоненты.
3. Откажитесь от jq,
   делайте всё через react.  Реализуйте всё, что делал jq, через react.